# Kafka integration with RDBMS

Tags: apache-kafka

Can someone help me with the steps to integrate Kafka with RDBMS, I have to stream data from a table into spark mllib. Any solution other than Kafka will also help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to read data from one source and save it into any data base. You can achieve this using kafka-producer and kafka-consumer.

to learn more about kafka [visit](http://kafka.apache.org/)